# How to traverse over multiple matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab

I've a mat file which when loaded gives me something like this:

train0:[1200x300]
train1:[1450x300]
.
.
.
.
.
.
trainN:[Nx300]

what I want to do is traverse over each matrices in a manner like train+"i" where i = 0 to N
and create a NX1 matrix with value of i. Here N will be the number of rows in each of the train matrices.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Can you please better explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try loading the file into a sturct

```
ld = load(matfilename);
numRow = structfun( @(x) size(x,1), ld );
```

A more complicated method might be:

```
ld = load(matfilename);
matNames = fieldnames( ld );
numRows = zeros( 1, numel(matNames) );
for fi = 1:nueml(matNames)
    tkn = regexp( matNames{fi}, '^train(\d+)$', 'tokens', 'once' );
    ii = str2double( tkn{1} );
    numRows(ii) = size( ld.(matNames{fi}), 1 );
end
```

Anyhow, loading the mat file into a struct allows you to manipulate all loaded matrices as struct fields.