# Run matlab command line and automate running unix server bjobs

Tags: bash, matlab, lsf

I'm running a chunk of matlab code called **fit.m** this way,

```
clear all;
load('/pathtomatfile/alldata.mat')
count = rxw1;
count = double(count);
x_cov = ltgbd;
```

alldata.mat has several data of interest, i.e.,

```
rxw1
rbg2
rfd1
wop3, 
ltgbd,
etc.
```

I can run such script from the command line for a given data of interest (in my example count=rxw1),

```
matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -r ${pathtoscript}fit -logfile lfile.txt
```

However, I need to automate the running so I can tell matlab to make count = any of the other datasets in the mat file.  I.e., I'd like to the script in parallel for different datasets but I'd need something like:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -r ${pathtoscript}fit -logfile lfile.txt DATAOFINTERESTHERE (i.e., rxw1 count will equal rxw1, etc.)
```

Is it possible to do what I am suggesting?  How would I automate the script to run for any of the datasets I choose by giving the name of the dataset as an input parameter when I call the script?

Once I have that  I plan to actually run them all in parallel by submitting jobs through LSF but giving the name of the data of interest as an input, something like this in mind:

```
bsub -q week -R'rusage[mem=8000]' \
"matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -r ${pathtoscript}fit -logfile lfile.txt DATAOFINTEREST"
```

Sorry if it's too basic of a Q but I am not familiar with running matlab command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `fit` a function, instead of script. The `fit` **function** can have a single input variable pointing to the right data file.
Then you can run

```
matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -r "cd ${pathtoscript}; fit('${dataofinterest}');exit;"
```

**EDIT:** added this detailed `fit` fun.

Your `fit` function should look something like

```
function fit( variableName )
%
% run fit for a specific variable from the mat file
% variableName is a string, e.g. variableName = 'rgb1';
%

ld = load('/pathtomatfile/alldata.mat');
count = ld.(variableName); % access variables in mat file as struct fields
count = double( count );
% and I believe you can take it from here...
```

**EDIT:**
Similar solution loading mat file into a struct to handle the loaded variables
can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545688/how-to-traverse-over-multiple-matrices-in-matlab) with some more details.

Comment: thanks a lot.  It does not solve my problem though since I do not have many mat files.  The mat file is only one file, and inside there I have all the data(variables) I am interested in, that's the main issue I face.  I could try splitting such file but was looking for something more convenient.

Comment: @Dnaiel I edited my answer, I believe it can solve your problem now.